# Recover From Changing Host IP#

Tags: google-compute-engine

I was trying to add an IP# to my Google Compute Engine (RHEL7) instance, but I typed the invocation wrong:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 1.2.3.4
```

The existing IP# on eth0 was 1.2.3.3, so that invocation changed my existing IP# to one that isn't known to anything else. And so I lost all connections (ssh, http, even ping) to the instance.

How do I recover from this mistake? Is there a gcloud or GCP Console method I can use, since I can't connect directly to the instance anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ifconfig was invoked from a shell, not reconfigured in any startup scripts (or anywhere else), just resetting the instance will reboot it and cause it to config its eth0 according to its startup scripts:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list
NAME      ZONE        MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
<instance-name>  <instance-zone>  <machine-type>  <preemptible>  <bad-internal-ip#>  <external-ip#>  
$ gcloud compute instances reset <instance-name>
For the following instance:
 - [<instance-name>]
choose a zone:
 [1] asia-east1-a
 [2] asia-east1-b
[...]
Please enter your numeric choice:  <N-of-instance-zone>

Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<project-name>/zones/<instance-zone>/instances/<instance-name].
$ gcloud compute instances list
NAME      ZONE        MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
<instance-name>  <instance-zone>  <machine-type>  <preemptible>  <default-internal-ip#>  <external-ip#>  RUNNING
```

After you enter your numeric zone it can take several seconds or a longer (but probably not more than 5 minutes) for the instance to restart.

Answer (score 0):

Look around in the cloud platform console. You usually can change the external IP, then go the long way around - provided its instanced.

Comment: 1. So I'd use the Cloud Platform console to change the external IP#, which will reveal further actions that include changing the internal IP#?

Comment: The hope is that if you change the External IP, you can HTTP into it and change the internalIP

Comment: If you haven't messed up the External IP, try to connect to it now.

Comment: Actually while looking around in the cloud platform console I found the gcloud compute instances reset <instance-name> command that reboots the machine, so it comes back up with its originally configured (as per its startup scripts, ie. DHCP) internal IP#. Thanks for the lead (and the confidence that it wasn't doomed :).